# Best way to define a Customized authorization policy

Tags: authorization, mongodb

I am developing a project with MongoDB, I have a scenario where I can restrict the visibility of data to the user based on their role, for example if I have a document of the form:

```
{
   "testme1":"fooo",
  "testme2":"foobar"
}
```

A user with role `"admin"` can see both `"testme1"` and `"testme2"`, whereas `"guest"` can see only `"testme2"`.

What is the best way to define these authorization rule dynamically, so that my wrapper API should fetch the data only as per the rule. My approach of doing is to give the user a web "UI" to define a rule and based on his declaration keep a "XML" file in my server. Please let me know if someone has a better idea or if their is some Database level approach to do this

Comment: Normally I would say to use 'views', but MongoDB doesn't support views.  Could we get a little more info about the structure of the data you want to restrict?  How would an app identify which data to restrict?  Can you use something like a sub-query (query your data from the result of another query which restricts the available data)?

Comment: This may be a better question for a database stack exchange.

Comment: Question is not related to database,but filter out data extracted from it

Comment: data I fetch will be mainly in jSON format

Comment: Part of a databases job normally is to filter and potentially structure the data which it returns.

Comment: I'm guessing the json formatted file is stored as a single entry in the DB correct?  If so then you *need* to do this in the software and not the db.

Comment: That is mainly based on some PlSQL or view, but the first thing is MongoDB do not support all those,secondly the user authorization policy changes dynamically , so guess DB approach wont work

Comment: Please refer my question :)

Answer (score 2):

For Authorization its better for you to go with XACML 3.0 Policy based Attribute level Access Control.

[XACML](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=xacml)

Answer (score 0):

In information security there is a concept called 'row level security'.  This would mean that different users see the same database differently, with certain rows omitted or obscured (in a way which still allows for statistical analysis).

Your best bet may be to take your JSON files and convert them into database records.  Basically parse your JSON files and insert them into a database table.  Then implement row level security on the table, and write a stored procedure.

The stored procedure will request the records for the particular user specified, then convert the results into a JSON script (or you can do the conversion in the application).

Comment: It depends on your specific database implementation how the RLS policy is defined.

Comment: @Daisetu we have migrated from RDBMS to NoSQL for performance and cannot store data in RDBMS just for security purpose

Comment: You may want to include that in your question.  It seems your hands are sorta tied at the DB level.  You might have to create a custom solution.

Comment: As I have mentioned "My approach of doing is to give the user a web "UI" to define a rule and based on his declaration keep a "XML" file in my server."